# Firebase Firestore Server Timestamp with firebase-admin python sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

There is a way to add server timestamps in **firebase-admin python sdk**?
I try:

```
firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
firestore.constants.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
```

but, i get this exception:

```
TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', <object object at 0x10380fc20>, 'Invalid type', <class 'object'>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` worked for me. Here's the full example:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

# I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS configured.
firebase_admin.initialize_app()
client = firestore.client()
result = client.collection('test').document('foo').set({
    'mytime':firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
})
print(result)
```

This printed out:

```
update_time {
  seconds: 1523491166
  nanos: 932097000
}
```

And the value was stored in database as expected.

Comment: Current version works with this code  `firestore.firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`