# how store the firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP in array

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to archive and then update an array which contains many `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` in firestore, but when I take this document and do

```
accesses.update({ u"mylist": [firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP]})
```

It throws

```
TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', Sentinel: Value used to set a document field to the server timestamp., 'Invalid type', <class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1.transforms.Sentinel'>)
```

So, it is possible to do this storing? How?

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783651/firebase-firestore-server-timestamp-with-firebase-admin-python-sdk) is a similar question.

There shows a code like this:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

# I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS configured.
firebase_admin.initialize_app()
client = firestore.client()
result = client.collection('test').document('foo').set({
    'mytime':firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
})
print(result)
```

This printed out:

```
update_time {
  seconds: 1523491166
  nanos: 932097000
}
```

And the value was stored in database as expected.

Comment: yes, it works. but I said a different thing. I would like to store an array of firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP, it store only a single value.

Comment: Have you tried with `ArrrayUnion`? Should be somethinkg like:

`accesses.update({ u"mylist": firestore.ArrayUnion([firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP])})`