# Firebase Firestore server timestamp fails when in list, using firebase-admin python sdk

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I followed directions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783651/firebase-firestore-server-timestamp-with-firebase-admin-python-sdk) to insert a server timestamp in my firestore data, and it works fine as long as the timestamp is inside a map.  But if the map is further embedded in a list, it fails.  Is this not allowed?

Here is the test code:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app()
client = firestore.client()
doc_ref = client.collection('test').document('timetest')
changes = {
    'name': 'test name',
    'timetest': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
}
print('Writing timestamp without list')
doc_ref.set({'test_nolist': changes})
print('Writing timestamp inside a list')
doc_ref.set({'test_withlist': [changes]})
```

Here is the output including error:

```
Writing timestamp without list
Writing timestamp inside a list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firestore_write.py", line 477, in <module>
    testTimestamp()
  File "firestore_write.py", line 466, in testTimestamp
    incident_doc_ref.set({'test_withlist': [changes]})
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 233, in set
    batch.set(self, document_data, merge=merge)
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/batch.py", line 88, in set
    reference._document_path, document_data
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 625, in pbs_for_set_no_merge
    write_pbs = [extractor.get_update_pb(document_path)]
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 483, in get_update_pb
    name=document_path, fields=encode_dict(self.set_fields)
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 215, in encode_dict
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 215, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 190, in encode_value
    value_list = [encode_value(element) for element in value]
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 190, in <listcomp>
    value_list = [encode_value(element) for element in value]
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 195, in encode_value
    value_dict = encode_dict(value)
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 215, in encode_dict
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 215, in <dictcomp>
    return {key: encode_value(value) for key, value in six.iteritems(values_dict)}
  File "/Users/fred/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 200, in encode_value
    "Cannot convert to a Firestore Value", value, "Invalid type", type(value)
TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', Sentinel: Value used to set a document field to the server timestamp., 'Invalid type', <class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1.transforms.Sentinel'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the misunderstanding,if you need to manipulate a list I think you could use something like this:

accesses.update({ u"mylist":firestore.ArrayUnion([firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP])})

You can find a complete example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Comment: Firestore's set function doesn't allow to set each element of a list field one by one, you need to pass the complete list, so your fix won't work.

Comment: hi, you was right, I update the, I hope this will help you